# How many users can receive SMS in 1 minute if delay is acceptable

Tags: algorithm, math, sms, twilio

This at first seems to be a simple calculation but it is not.

According to Twilio I can send one SMS per second per phone. So if a user **must** receive an SMS within one second, then with one phone, I can send 60 SMS in 60 seconds. But what if a 5 second wait is okay. And what if I have 5 phones instead of one. Then how many users can satisfactorily receive SMS within one minute?

*what if I change to 8 phones instead of 5?*

Again, satisfaction means the user gets the SMS within 5 seconds, as in `(0,5]`.

I need to know the answer so I know how many phone numbers to buy from Twilio. I am rolling out my own SMS-verification for my mobile app. Thanks.

Comment: " if a user must receive an SMS" - Wrong technology. SMS is not in the least reliable, let alone time-bound. Sure, delivery often is fast, but 24 hours delay or a total loss can happen. That's why they're cheap: delivery is a best-effort attempt.

Comment: I think you are looking at the problem wrongly. As @MSalters pointed out SMS technology is not time bound nor safe/reliable so sending does not mean receiving. You should check your service provider transmit network devices for their capabilities because SMS receive rate has almost nothing to do with SMS send rate ... but that is mine opinion so correct me if I am wrong (it is a quite few years I have to do something with telecommunication devices) and be careful what to look for because SMS are not using normal data channels but  debug/maintenance channels instead

Comment: @Spektre: That's pre-GPRS GSM. And it wasn't the maintenance or debug channel, but the signalling channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ideal conditions:

`users = max_delay * rate * nb_phones`

5s * 1/s * 8 phones = 40 concurrent users

The 1 minute period doesn't say anything since what matters is when the user makes the request, at that can happen at any given time.

That's how fast you can theoretically send ignoring the time taken by the actual network requests, server queuing etc. In the real world I expect the value to be less than that, so account for an error margin.

This doesn't say anything about how fast the client will receive the SMS.

If you are in US/Canada/UK you can look into [shortcodes](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/short-codes).

> From the FAQ: Twilio short codes can send 30 messages per second by default; this limit can be raised for an additional fee. Because short codes can send high volumes of messages, wireless carriers individually approve every short code for its intended use. This approval process typically takes 12 to 16 weeks.

Comment: Not sure why you think shortcodes are limited to 30 messages/s. Back in 2003 we were already pushing out close to 500 messages/second. (Gameshow voting)

Comment: Actually the per minute rate matters to me, since that's the period I am asking about. otherwise the misleading assumption of 40*60 = 24000 would hold

Comment: I'm not sure what you need to measure by that minute rate. Suppose you have 100 users who need to receive the SMS in maximum 5s. With 8 phones 40 of those users will receive the SMS in 5s, another 40 between 5-10s and the rest after 10s. Only 40 users are satisfied. If you need a minute rate you need to consider an average time between requests.